# properties files in jar with windows path

Tags: java, linux, windows, jar

We are working on a project wehre there are some legacy jar files getting used in an application. Some of the JAR files have the ".properties" file path hardcoded in code (in class files).

```
private static Configuration getGlobalConfigInstance() {
    if (global_config_instance == null)
        try {
            global_config_instance = (Configuration) new PropertiesConfiguration("D:/Apps/config/properties/MyWeb.properties");
        } catch (ConfigurationException configurationException) {
            configurationException.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

    return global_config_instance;
}
```

Now we are moving this application from Windows to Linux, is there a way to use these JAR files without recompiling?